# .NET Simple chat server example

Tags: c#, sockets

I was looking for the simple step by step communication tutorial for .Net programmers.  After some Google queries, I have found the "CSharp Communications" code collections at net-informations.com. It looked quite good as long as I reached the "[How to C# Chat Server](http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-chat-server.htm)" example.

Authors propose multithreaded server with the HashTable container to keep all connections in the shared memory at the server side. According to MSDN documentation [TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) and [NetworkStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.aspx) classes used for broadcast messages are not thread safe, while the example uses them from multiple server threads.

My questions are:

1. Could you confirm that the example is wrong?
2. How should it be done, is it enough to lock the broadcast method (mark it as a critical section)?
3. Could you recommend some socket communication tutorials (.Net preferred)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to MSDN documentation TcpClient and NetworkStream classes used for broadcast messages are not thread safe, while the example uses them from multiple server threads.

This is correct; but it is about concurrent access. If each thread uses the instance in turn (eg. using locks to control access) then different threads *can* be used.

In other words: not thread safe does not imply tied to a single thread.

Comment: There are many threads at the server side broadcasting messages to many clients connected to the server.

Comment: @kuszi See my first paragraph: avoid two threads both accessing the same socket at exactly the same time via locking.

Answer (score 6):

It is not perfect as I wrote it almost 7 years ago, but it is covering and will give you good understanding regarding the field of TCP communications:

[Generic TCP/IP Client Server](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19307/Generic-TCP-IP-Client-Server)

Comment: -1 - [Stack Overflow is not Your Free Promotional Site™](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128560/140505).

Comment: I replied to his question: "Could you recommend some socket communication tutorials (.Net preferred)?"
(Code-Project is not my site! very insulting that you would judge my motives like that.)

Comment: Well, that part of the question is considered off-topic on Stack Overflow. See [Stack Overflow is not a Link Farm or Search Engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128549/140505). You have also disregarded the other parts of the question that are on topic.

Comment: I think that his question is in the spirit of the site and my answer is as well - but you have a point as well and I can see why you would question my motives - so, i'll let the community decide. If even 1 more person would think that I am out of line and demote my answer - so be it - I will be happy to remove it.

Comment: I would vote up, if you would do the courtesy of adding a bit of a summary. Other than that it's exactly what the op is asking for.

Comment: Thanks Mike, do you mean adding summary of what is in the tutorial? I'm not sure I understand what you meant.